# Javascript issue <span>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem.

```
<p> hi my <span>name</span> is Alex. I got my <span>name</span> from my grandpa.
```

Is it any Javascript code I could use so that i change all the span tags? And not separately like [0, 1]?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Change them how? What do you mean by "not separately"?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I've fixed it for you this time.)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow Alex, post what code you've tried? then we can help you to change all the span tags

Comment: Select the divs, loop over them, change the text

Answer (score 0):

how's your grandpa doing?

```
// Grab all <span> tags
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

// Loop over them, and do something to them
spans.forEach((individualSpan, index) => {
  individualSpan.innerHTML = 'This is span number ' + index;
})
```